Android Compose draw Path to erase foreground
I am educating myself by messing around a bit with the canvas in a Composable.
The idea I am looking for is to:

Have a background color ( in this case just doing a gradient of colors)
Black foreground covering the background
Draw a path on the screen that will, in a sense, erase the black foreground where it is drawn on to expose the background.

I have successfully done this but I am a little confused on how it needs to work the way I stumbled across the solution. Maybe it is not right after all and I am going about it the wrong way.
Below is my code:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    //enableEdgeToEdge()
    setContent {
        SampleScratchPadTheme {

            var reset by remember {
                mutableStateOf(false)
            }

            Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), floatingActionButton = {
                FloatingActionButton(onClick = {
                    reset = true
                }, shape = RoundedCornerShape(25.dp)) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.Refresh,
                        contentDescription = "Restart"
                    )
                }
            }) { innerPadding ->

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .padding(innerPadding)
                ) {
                    Column {
                        Sample(reset, resetCanvas = {
                            reset = false
                        })
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun Sample(
    reset : Boolean,
    resetCanvas : () -> Unit
) {

    var circles = remember {
        mutableStateListOf(Offset(-100f, -100f)) // start off screen
    }

    var erasedPoints by remember {
        mutableStateOf(Path())
    }

    fun changeColor(): List<Color> {
        return listOf(
            Color(
                Random.nextInt(255),
                Random.nextInt(255),
                Random.nextInt(255),
                255
            ),
            Color(
                Random.nextInt(255),
                Random.nextInt(255),
                Random.nextInt(255),
                255
            ),
            Color(
                Random.nextInt(255),
                Random.nextInt(255),
                Random.nextInt(255),
                255
            )
        )
    }

    var gradientColors by remember {
        mutableStateOf(changeColor())
    }

    var pointerOffset by remember {
        mutableStateOf(Offset(0f, 0f))
    }

    if(reset){
        circles.clear()
        erasedPoints.reset()
        gradientColors = changeColor()
        resetCanvas()
    }

    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .clipToBounds()
        .pointerInput("dragging") {
            detectDragGestures(onDragStart = {
                pointerOffset = it
                erasedPoints.moveTo(pointerOffset.x, pointerOffset.y)
                circles.add(pointerOffset)
            }) { change, dragAmount ->
                pointerOffset += dragAmount
                erasedPoints.lineTo(pointerOffset.x, pointerOffset.y)
                circles.add(pointerOffset)

            }
        }
        .drawBehind {
            drawRect(
                brush = Brush.linearGradient(
                    colors = gradientColors,
                    start = Offset.Zero,
                    end = Offset.Infinite
                )
            )
        }
        .drawWithContent {
            drawRect(Color.Black)
            circles.forEach {
                drawCircle(
                    brush = Brush.linearGradient(
                        colors = gradientColors,
                        start = Offset.Zero,
                        end = Offset.Infinite
                    ), center = it,
                    radius = 25f,
                    blendMode = BlendMode.SrcIn
                )
            }
            if (!erasedPoints.isEmpty) {
                drawPath(
                    path = erasedPoints,
                    brush = Brush.linearGradient(
                        colors = gradientColors,
                        start = Offset.Zero,
                        end = Offset.Infinite
                    ),
                    style = Stroke(
                        width = 50f,
                        cap = StrokeCap.Round,
                        join = StrokeJoin.Round
                    ),
                    blendMode = BlendMode.SrcIn
                )
            }
        }) {

    }
}

}
The part that gets me confused is:
drawRect(Color.Black)
        circles.forEach {
            drawCircle(
                brush = Brush.linearGradient(
                    colors = gradientColors,
                    start = Offset.Zero,
                    end = Offset.Infinite
                ), center = it,
                radius = 25f,
                blendMode = BlendMode.SrcIn
            )
        }
        if (!erasedPoints.isEmpty) {
            drawPath(
                path = erasedPoints,
                brush = Brush.linearGradient(
                    colors = gradientColors,
                    start = Offset.Zero,
                    end = Offset.Infinite
                ),
                style = Stroke(
                    width = 50f,
                    cap = StrokeCap.Round,
                    join = StrokeJoin.Round
                ),
                blendMode = BlendMode.SrcIn
            )
        }


The image shows the wanted results but it only works when I add the drawPath and loop through the drawCircle methods.
If I keep just drawPath and remove drawCircle loop, which is what I would imagine is all that is needed, then nothing happens to screen. Just black.
If I change the blendmode to BlendMode.CLEAR in the drawCircle, I get this:

It just seems unnecessary to have both methods. I would think all I need is drawPath.
Any info or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
*************              ANSWER         **************
Thanks to Thracian I decided to update my code in case anyone else may need to reference. I didn't follow his example, just adjustments to the two issues he pointed out. Meaning minimal editing just for my proof of concept.
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    //enableEdgeToEdge()
    setContent {
        SampleScratchPadTheme {

            var reset by remember {
                mutableStateOf(false)
            }

            Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), floatingActionButton = {
                FloatingActionButton(onClick = {
                    reset = true
                }, shape = RoundedCornerShape(25.dp)) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.Refresh,
                        contentDescription = "Restart"
                    )
                }
            }) { innerPadding ->

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .padding(innerPadding)
                ) {
                    Column {
                        Sample(reset, resetCanvas = {
                            reset = false
                        })
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun Sample(
    reset : Boolean,
    resetCanvas : () -> Unit
) {

    var circles = remember {
        mutableStateListOf(Offset(-100f, -100f)) // start off screen
    }

    var erasedPoints by remember {
        mutableStateOf(Path())
    }

    fun changeColor(): List<Color> {
        return listOf(
            Color(
                Random.nextInt(255),
                Random.nextInt(255),
                Random.nextInt(255),
                255
            ),
            Color(
                Random.nextInt(255),
                Random.nextInt(255),
                Random.nextInt(255),
                255
            ),
            Color(
                Random.nextInt(255),
                Random.nextInt(255),
                Random.nextInt(255),
                255
            )
        )
    }

    var gradientColors by remember {
        mutableStateOf(changeColor())
    }

    var pointerOffset by remember {
        mutableStateOf(Offset(0f, 0f))
    }

    if(reset){
        circles.clear()
        erasedPoints.reset()
        gradientColors = changeColor()
        pointerOffset = Offset.Unspecified
        resetCanvas()
    }

    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .clipToBounds()
        .pointerInput("dragging") {
            detectDragGestures(onDragStart = {
                pointerOffset = it
                erasedPoints.moveTo(pointerOffset.x, pointerOffset.y)
                circles.add(pointerOffset)
            }) { change, dragAmount ->
                pointerOffset += dragAmount
                erasedPoints.lineTo(pointerOffset.x, pointerOffset.y)
                circles.add(pointerOffset)

            }
        }
        .drawBehind {
            drawRect(
                brush = Brush.linearGradient(
                    colors = gradientColors,
                    start = Offset.Zero,
                    end = Offset.Infinite
                )
            )
        }
        .graphicsLayer {
            compositingStrategy = CompositingStrategy.Offscreen
        }
        .drawWithContent {
            drawRect(Color.Black)
            /*circles.forEach {
                drawCircle(
                    brush = Brush.linearGradient(
                        colors = gradientColors,
                        start = Offset.Zero,
                        end = Offset.Infinite
                    ), center = it,
                    radius = 25f,
                    blendMode = BlendMode.SrcIn
                )
            }*/
            if(pointerOffset != Offset.Unspecified){
            if (!erasedPoints.isEmpty) {
                drawPath(
                    path = erasedPoints,
                    color = Color.Transparent,
                    style = Stroke(
                        width = 50f,
                        cap = StrokeCap.Round,
                        join = StrokeJoin.Round
                    ),
                    blendMode = BlendMode.Clear
                )
            }
            }
        }) {

    }
}

}

The issue here as you can observe with circles is not reading a observable or State inside drawScope during drawing. Your path does not change, only its inner properties change.
If you check this answer about how to draw on Canvas using touch events you can see that position which is a MutableState is passed to Canvas's drawScope to trigger draw phase on each position change.
You can change your Composable like this
@Composable
private fun Sample(
    reset: Boolean,
    resetCanvas: () -> Unit,
) {

    val erasedPoints by remember {
        mutableStateOf(Path())
    }

    var motionEvent by remember { mutableStateOf(MotionEvent.Idle) }

    fun changeColor(): List<Color> {
        return listOf(
            Color(
                Random.nextInt(255),
                Random.nextInt(255),
                Random.nextInt(255),
                255
            ),
            Color(
                Random.nextInt(255),
                Random.nextInt(255),
                Random.nextInt(255),
                255
            ),
            Color(
                Random.nextInt(255),
                Random.nextInt(255),
                Random.nextInt(255),
                255
            )
        )
    }

    var gradientColors by remember {
        mutableStateOf(changeColor())
    }

    var pointerOffset by remember {
        mutableStateOf(Offset.Unspecified)
    }

    if (reset) {
        erasedPoints.reset()
        gradientColors = changeColor()
        resetCanvas()
    }

    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .clipToBounds()
        .pointerInput("dragging") {
            detectDragGestures(
                onDragCancel = {
                    motionEvent = MotionEvent.Up
                    pointerOffset = Offset.Unspecified

                },
                onDragEnd = {
                    motionEvent = MotionEvent.Up
                    pointerOffset = Offset.Unspecified
                },
                onDragStart = {
                    motionEvent = MotionEvent.Down
                    pointerOffset = it
                    erasedPoints.moveTo(pointerOffset.x, pointerOffset.y)
                }
            ) { change, dragAmount ->
                pointerOffset += dragAmount
                motionEvent = MotionEvent.Move
            }
        }
        .drawBehind {
            drawRect(
                brush = Brush.linearGradient(
                    colors = gradientColors,
                    start = Offset.Zero,
                    end = Offset.Infinite
                )
            )
        }

        .graphicsLayer {
            compositingStrategy = CompositingStrategy.Offscreen
        }
        .drawWithContent {
            drawRect(Color.Black)

           if (
                motionEvent == MotionEvent.Move &&
                pointerOffset != Offset.Unspecified
            ) {
                erasedPoints.lineTo(pointerOffset.x, pointerOffset.y)
            }

            if (erasedPoints.isEmpty.not()) {
                drawPath(
                    path = erasedPoints,
                    color = Color.Transparent,
                    style = Stroke(
                        width = 50f,
                        cap = StrokeCap.Round,
                        join = StrokeJoin.Round
                    ),
                    blendMode = BlendMode.Clear
                )
            }
        }) {
    }
}

Second issue is applying blendMode to erase from black background. For blend modes to work correctly you need to set composition strategy or offscreen buffer.
Jetpack Compose Applying PorterDuffMode to Image
And apply blendMode to path with clear to remove black while creating a scratch like effect displaying gradient beneath black rectangle.


Amazing! That helped me wrap my brain around this. I see the issues. .graphicsLayer {             compositingStrategy = CompositingStrategy.Offscreen         } I would have completely missed. Then the state change in composable is a big miss on my end.

Yes, in either phases, Composition, Layout or Draw if you need continuous updates you need to read a State in these phases. And some blend works don't work correctly without creating an offscreen buffer. You can use alpha less than 1f, save/restore layer or  CompositingStrategy.Offscreen or new GraphicsLayer object
